# Adding my own library to Contiki OS

Tags: c, cpu-architecture, msp430, contiki

I want to add some third party libraries to Contiki, but at the moment I can't.
So I wanted to just test with a simple library.

I wrote two files hello.c hello.h, in hello.c I have:

```
printf(" Hello everbody, library call\n");
```

In hello.h I have:

```
extern void print_hello();
```

I created hello.o using the command:

```
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f1611 hello.c -o hello.o
```

I created an archive file:

```
ar -cvq libhello.a hello.o
```

I move to contiki, i write a simple program that calls hello.h to execute a function.I try to include hello.a using PROJECT LIBRARIES variable in the makefile, when i compile i get this :

```
  Hello_lib.sky section .vectors' will not fit in region'vectors'
  ...
  region vectors overflowed by 32 Bytes
```

Can someone please explain me what is the problem (I am new to the field) ?

And how to correct it if possible? ( What options should i specify for msp430-gcc)
Thanks.

Comment: Which architecture are you trying compile for? Wismote or `msp430f2131`? Wismote uses Series 5 MSP430 and MSP430F2131 is from Series 2: a completely different family.

Comment: I'm not aiming a deployable code, just want to perofrm a simulation. So let's say i want to use Skymote ( msp430f1611), thanks for the comment  anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you build the library for the same architecture you build your program.

For example, if you want to use build an executable for `sky` motes (MSP430F1611 MCU), build the library with:

```
msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f1611 -c hello.c -o hello.o
msp430-ar -cvq libhello.a hello.o
```

Then add the path to the library and its name to application's Makefile:

```
TARGET_LIBFILES += -L./hellolib -lhello
```

Then build the application as usual:

```
make TARGET=sky
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was so blind i didn t notice msp430-ar insteed of ar command. Again thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

This video shows how to add your own libraries to Contiki OS

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csa9D1U5R_8

Details:

- The library that i create is: libhello.a
- The library just prints the message "Hello everbody, library call"
- I included the library to the Contiki example "example-broadcast.c"

Steps of the video:

1. Create folder example:

   - Copy the example-broadcast.c
   - Copy the Makefile
2. Create the library:

   - Create object file:

     ```
     msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430f1611 -c hello.c -o hello.o
     ```
   - Create library file:

     ```
     msp430-ar -cvq libhello.a hello.o
     ```
3. Tell Contiki the path to the library:

   ```
       TARGET_LIBFILES += -L. -lhello
   ```
4. Add the library to your .c code and print the hello message:

   ```
    #include "hello.h"
    Print_Function();
   ```
5. Compile your .c code:

   ```
    make example-broadcast TARGET=sky
   ```