# How I can link c-libraries with COOJA ContikiOS?

Tags: c, ubuntu, static-linking, contiki, cooja

I am working on COOJA and want to use cryptographic functions like hashing. So, I need libraries like libsodium and libtomcrypt. I have tried following different possible solutions:

1. Including link of the library in the project's makefile. It gives fatal error: sodium.h no such file or directory.
2. Making the library and headers inside the project. There is no error regarding "sodium.h" but is

   > sodium/crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.h:68:52: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
   >   sodium/crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.h:68:55: error: expected ';'. '.' or ')' before 'uint32_t'
3. Using msp430-gcc to compile a file contains libsodium functions.  First used no.2 solution and then [Adding my own library to Contiki OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971717/adding-my-own-library-to-contiki-os) and same

   > sodium/crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.h:68:52: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
   >   sodium/crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.h:68:55: error: expected ';'. '.' or ')' before 'uint32_t'

What is real problem here due to which I can't link libsodium? How can I solve this?

Comment: Take the [tour], read [ask], and [mcve]. Post output text, not links to images of text.